kdenlive renders choppy video
I've just started trying out kdenlive and I can't get it to render nice smooth video output to the same quality as my input.  No matter how high I set the quality settings the rendered video I get from kdenlive is really choppy, much less smooth than my input.  Could this be an unavoidable problem with something Melt is doing to the video before it even gets to ffmpeg?

I had the same issue and I simply copied the exported video into a different location (I don't know if the location is important) and it fixed it instantly. No clue why this worked but hey, I'll take the win.
